# Edit user account how to check before update if the role check box is selected?

Tags: 7, users

I have a module that when my user changes the user details `hook_user` onupdate, pushes these details to an external database. However I would like this to only work when role X is selected, else my module will not do anything. The role will not be in the users profile as this processing is happening before I update the users account.

Drupal 6
Thanks

**Update**

```
 function checkrole_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL){
 switch($op){
 case 'submit':

  if ($edit['roles'] == 'Staff'){
  do xyz
    }

  }
```

[image: Edit user form]

Comment: Please don't change question in response to an answer. It's called [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745) and it really really makes people dislike you and think twice if it's worth to answer you, if all they got is no upvotes, but a change in question that renders their answer irrelevant. You can always ask new, follow up question, linking to the previous one.

Comment: I was just trying to keep it relevant, no major change made, apart from i removed a block of code that was not relevant to the question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use [`hook_user_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) for any logic that you need to happen before user data is really updated, but also have access to new values:

> **Parameters**
>
> **`$edit`**: The array of form values submitted by the user. Assign values to this array to save changes in the database.
>
> **`$account`**: The user object on which the operation is performed. Values assigned in this object will not be saved in the database.
>
> **`$category`**: The active category of user information being edited.

You need to test against `$edit` argument.

---

For Drupal 6, you need [`hook_user`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_user/6).

> Act on user account actions.

Act when `$op == 'submit'`, as:

> **submit**: Modify the account before it gets saved.

Just as with Drupal 7, you must examine

> **`$edit`**: The array of form values submitted by the user.

Comment: I totally forgot to say I am using Drupal 6 here

Comment: @Tom answer updated

Comment: Thanks, that make sense I had used hook_user after update before to make the changes. I did adjust the code in my original question, is there a way to print contents of the $edit, I tried print_r (no luck). So that I can find what I need to be checking against in my if statement. Before I would use $edit['name']; to view the user name, but I am not sure what part of the array holds whether the role has been selected

Comment: @Tom to print contents of the $edit, install [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module and use one of it's functions, for example `dpm($edit)`.

Comment: I am using the devel module now however am coming across issues with internal errors, when I use a second hook_user in the same module, please see [link] (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98050/using-hook-user-submit-and-after-update-in-the-same-module).