# Using hook_user submit and after_update in the same module

Tags: 6, hooks

Extending from [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97904/edit-user-account-how-to-check-before-update-if-the-role-check-box-is-selected?noredirect=1#comment114569_97904) question (I am now using devel, and know that I need to compare r.rid in my logic), I am trying to place a query into my drupal 6 module, that checks that a certain role has been selected prior to save. if `after_update` will push these details to an external database. `else` the normal drupal functionality will be the only function.

My code looks like the below, with the bottom hook_user working correctly. If I place the first hook_user (submit) into my module I start getting internal server errors.

Any suggestios?

```
 function assigncoordinator_user($op, &$edit, &$account){
 switch($op){
 case 'submit':
       drupal_set_message(t('Legend worked'), 'error');
    } 
   }


function assigncoordinator_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL){
 switch($op){
 case 'after_update':
  //The rest of my code.......................
```

**Extra info**

```
If (r.rid = 25) { //How to I check this

function assigncoordinator_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL){
 switch($op){
 case 'after_update':
  //The rest of my code.......................
 }
 }
 } else {
 //do nothing
 }
```

Comment: You should not declare `assigncoordinator_user()` function twice in `drupal` site.

Comment: ahh ok thanks. I added an extra example of what I am attempting to do. How would I pull the currently selected role id before it has been submitted? on the user edit pages. @JayendraKainthola

Comment: @Tom 2 PHP bugs in one question. Don't get me wrong but could you try to play with basics, like PHP logic and loops, for few days, and only then come back to Drupal? It'll save everyone's time. Including you. `Switch` has no `else`.

Comment: @tom, you should not include `assigncoordinator_user()` function in if condition.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola actually it's not uncommon to conditionally define functions and classes. Of course here it may make a little less sense. But in general, it is OK.

Comment: @Mołot, yes, we can define in general case. But, here `r.rid` is not define and it will always show the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not allow multiple functions with same name. That's the point of the `case` statement there. Instead of

```
 function assigncoordinator_user($op, &$edit, &$account){
 switch($op){
 case 'submit':
       drupal_set_message(t('Legend worked'), 'error');
    } 
   }


function assigncoordinator_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL){
 switch($op){
 case 'after_update':
```

you should:

```
function assigncoordinator_user($op, &$edit, &$account){
  switch($op){
    case 'submit':
      drupal_set_message(t('Legend worked'), 'error');
      break;
    case 'after_update':
      // Your other code
      break;
  } 
}
```